# Is it possible to set the version number of the MSI when building a setup project(vdproj) from command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, vdproj

I need to build a setup project from command line and set the version number of the built msi from a parameter. Is it possible to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not possible. You'd have to rewrite the .VDPROJ as a prebuild step or update the MSI as a postbuild step. One of the many limitations of the toolset

Answer (score 0):

I created a vbs script that can accomplish what Christopher suggested in his answer. You need to execute this script before building the .vdproj. This script takes the .vdproj filename as first argument and the version as 2nd argument (**.**.** format) :

```
'Function that generates a new GUID
Function CreateGUID
  Dim TypeLib
  Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
  CreateGUID = Mid(TypeLib.Guid, 2, 36)
End Function

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

'Read vdproj filename and new version from arguments and generate new Guid
installerFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
newProductVersion = Wscript.Arguments(1)
newProductCode = CreateGUID()
newPackageCode = CreateGUID()

'Prepare Regexs
Set productVersionRegex = New RegExp
With productVersionRegex
 .Pattern    = Chr(34) & "ProductVersion" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:(.*)" & Chr(34)
 .IgnoreCase = False
End With

Set productCodeRegex = New RegExp
With productCodeRegex
 .Pattern    = Chr(34) & "ProductCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{(.*)}" & Chr(34)
 .IgnoreCase = False
End With

Set packageCodeRegex = New RegExp
With packageCodeRegex
 .Pattern    = Chr(34) & "PackageCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{(.*)}" & Chr(34)
 .IgnoreCase = False
End With

'Read Text from installer file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(installerFileName, ForReading)
installerText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

'Replace ProductVersion
newProductVersionString = Chr(34) & "ProductVersion" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:" & newProductVersion & Chr(34)
installerNewText = productVersionRegex.Replace(installerText, newProductVersionString)

'Replace ProductCode Guid
newProductCodeString = Chr(34) & "ProductCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{" & newProductCode & "}" & Chr(34)
installerNewText = productCodeRegex.Replace(installerNewText, newProductCodeString)

'Replace UpgradeCode  Guid
newPackageCodeString = Chr(34) & "PackageCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{" & newPackageCode & "}" & Chr(34)
installerNewText = packageCodeRegex.Replace(installerNewText, newPackageCodeString)

'Write new Text in installer file
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(installerFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write installerNewText
objFile.Close
```

The script can be called like this :

```
cscript script.vbs Installer.vdproj 1.2.5
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you could do that, you only need is a tool to update the project definition file **.vdproj. 
Take **.csproj as an example as below:
The project definition file like below (you need to open **.csproj file with notepad or something):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
   .......
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
```

"v4.0" is the target field to be replaced, after replace the filed then trigger the msbuild to build your project like "msbuild **.csproj"

Comment: VDPROJ doesn't use MSBUILD.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, because csproj file has nothing to do with the msi versioning. Rather editing the vdproj file that way might do it..

Comment: Yes, it's in the vdproj file - there's a Product section with line something like        "ProductVersion" = "8:1.0.0" where the 1.0.0 is the version. It's not Xml, it;s something internal.

Comment: This answer isn't even remotely useful.  Assuming one wanted to version a C# DLL the .CSPROJ isn't even the file to do it in.  You would update the AssemblyInfo.cs file.